# disable live click for element/image temporarily for a limited duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery `.live("click")` function for an image on click on which a textbox will become editable.

Now when i click some button(say check) I want to disable the live click of the image.

I dont want to hide the image.

I tried setting

```
$("#contact_no_edit_img, #email_edit_img")
    .attr("disabled", "disabled")
    .css("opacity","0.5");
```

but still the live click is working for that image

Is there any other way other than hiding the image or using a temporary variable to detect and allow live click ?!

Note: I dont want to change that to  .on as it would require us to recode the entire project !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually you should not use the .live() function anymore. Instead you should use `.on("click")` and `.off("click")`. You should see the jQuery docs about this: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: but it would require us to change a lot of functions so we thought we could go ahead with .live
Is there any other way for disabling .live() ?!

Comment: This website explains the reason why not to use live anymore.
http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/

Also live can be easily replaced by $(document).on('event','selector',function(){});

Comment: You don't need to replace every .live() function. You can only change the functions where you would like to use the .off("click) function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `die()` to remove a handler set with `live()`.

It's worth noting though that `live` and its associated functions have been deprecated since jQuery 1.7. You should really be using `on` with a delegate selector.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at `.off()` (the equivalent for `.unbind()` that works for dynamically created elements), **`.die()`** has been deprecated and **removed**, or even `.one()` which limits to a single event trigger per bound element.

Answer (score 1):

Can change selector for live?

```
$("#contact_no_edit_img:not([disabled=disabled])").live('click', function(){});
```

It will act only elements that does not have disabled="disabled"

Answer (score 0):

use die jquery for disable the click event

```
 $( "p" ).live( "click", callback function );

// Now foo will no longer be called
$( "p" ).die( "click", callback function );
```

Comment: `.live()` and `.die()` are both deprecated and removed